# Create an email containing the contents of specific cells when another cell has a certain value

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to create an email which summarizes items that have not been ordered. This macro will be assigned to a button.

I have an Excel sheet for requesting and tracking supply order requests.
There are four cells in each row of the table containing the item information (Vendor, Item Description, Part Number, Quantity) which are filled out by the person requesting the order.
Another cell is filled out with the order date by the person who orders the item.

The sheet name is "Order and Chemical Log".
The table containing the information is called Table8.
The table headers are located in row 10 of the sheet.
The cells containing the item information are in columns F, G, H, and I.
There is an indicator cell in column K which contains either "", "Ordered", or "Not ordered" based on if item information has been added to the row and if there is a date in the cell for marking that item as ordered.

I would like the body of the email to contain a text string ("The following items have not yet been ordered:") and a new line for each item which contain the item information (the values from the cells in columns F through I) *only* for items which not been ordered (the value in the cell in column K is "Not Ordered").

Code to generate an email to tell someone there are items to be ordered:

```vb
Sub SendOrderEmail()
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application 'Refers to outlook application
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application 'Launches outlook
Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem 'Refers to a new Outlook email
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'Lauches a new outlook email

On Error Resume Next
With EmailItem
    .To = "test@test.com"
    .Subject = "New Item(s) Added to Order Log"
    .HTMLBody = "Hi, <br> <br>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "I have added new items to the order log to be ordered today.<br><br>" & "Thank you, <br><br>""<br> Email Generated by VBA from the Order Log"
.Display
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have amended my title to be "when another cell contains a specific value ("Not Ordered")", NOT "when it is blank."

Comment: There are a list of things that *could* be done, e.g., writing each to an array, creating a string with each order that you append to, or copying the rows directly.  Of those, and if the data is simple, the single string approach would be simplest.  You can append to a string, adding commas/separators, as you loop through your cells in the spreadsheet.  Then, you can take that string (i would typically make this a global variable) that can be used within your email subroutine.

Comment: I see. I understand logically what you are saying here. Unfortunately, I don't have the know-how to go about implementing this as I'm very new to VBA but, I'll see what I can do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a simple table build the html as a string row by row.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SendOrderEmail()

    Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application 'Refers to outlook application
    Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application 'Launches outlook
    Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem 'Refers to a new Outlook email
    Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'Lauches a new outlook email
    
    Dim html As String
    html = getHtml
    If html = "" Then
        MsgBox "No 'not ordered' items found", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Debug.Print html
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With EmailItem
        .To = "test@test.com"
        .Subject = "New Item(s) Added to Order Log"
        .HTMLBody = getHtml
        .Display
    End With

End Sub

Function getHtml() As String

    Dim tbl As ListObject, n As Long
    Dim h As String, r As ListRow, c As Range
    
    With Sheets("Order and Chemical Log")
        Set tbl = .ListObjects("Table8")
    End With
    
    h = "<table style=""font:12px Verdana"" border=""1"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""3"">" & _
        "<tr style=""background-color:#f0f0d0;text-align:center;""><th>Vendor</th><th>Item Description</th>" & _
        "<th>Part Number</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>" & vbLf
    
    Dim i As Long, status As String
    With tbl
        i = .ListColumns("Vendor").Index ' vendor column
        For Each r In .ListRows
            status = LCase(Trim(r.Range(, i + 5))) ' 5 columns along from vendor
            If status = "not ordered" Then
                h = h & "<tr style=""text-align:center"">"
                For Each c In r.Range.Offset(, i - 1).Resize(, 4)
                   h = h & "<td>" & c.Value & "</td>"
                Next
                h = h & "</tr>" & vbLf
                n = n + 1
            Else
                Debug.Print r.Index, "'" & status & "'"
            End If
        Next
    End With
    h = h & "</table>"
    
    If n = 0 Then Exit Function ' no items
    
    getHtml = "Hi, <br/> <br/>" & _
        "I have added these items to the order log to be ordered today.<br/><br/>" & _
        vbLf & h & "<br/><br/>Thank you, <br/><br/> Email Generated by VBA from the Order Log"

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this. Initially it did not display an email at all. I changed  If html = "" Then  in the SendOrderEmail sub to  If html = "Not Ordered" Then. Now it displays a new email with the correct To and Subject fields however, the function getHtml does not  pull any data and there is no body text in the new email message.

Comment: @ESmS Does your table have more than 4 columns ? I have amended the code to allow for that. Change line back to `If html = "" Then`. If still no html check immediate window for output from `Debug.Print r.Index, "'" & status & "'"`

Comment: Yes my table is more complex than 4 columns. This works great! Thank you for the help.